# How can we get radio button values from form using body-parser on an expressjs server?

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I have a form and part of it asks the user if they are male or female. Here is the html,

```
<form role="form" id="createAccountForm" action="CAform" method="POST">
.
.
.
.
<div class="form-group" id="gender">
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">Male</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="0">Female</label>
</div>
.
.
.
</form>
```

and on the server (a node server with express framework), I want to know how to access the gender value when the user submits the form. Can you do it with body-parser?

Comment: Yes, what's the server side code? It will be something like `req.body.optradio`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the middlewares of bodyParser and you're good to go.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies

app.post('/CAForm', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.optradio);
});
```

Comment: these have been added to Express. bodyParser is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code. You can do it by using `req.body.optradio` and If you console log that you will get 1 or 0 as you have given those values in your value class.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although your code snippet may solve the OP problem, there is an already accepted answer that solved the problem providing more details than yours. In this case, the chance that your answer claim any attention and be upvoted is too small.