# Node.js delete record from SQLite database based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a simple node.js app which displays user login information stored in a SQLite database, with a radio button within each row. When the user selects a record and clicks the delete button, the appropriate record should be deleted.

The problem seems to be that I can't work out how to return the value of the selected radio button, they are all showing as 'undefined'. I have tried numerous different methods and am going around in circles. Help appreciated!

Edit: I think the issue is that I am using one GET method for everything, so the req.body is empty. Not sure how to fix it though!

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var path = require('path');
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();


// Open persistent file database "loginDB"
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./loginDB', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the user database.');
  });

// Route files in public
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Configure to use body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// Function to check if radio button is selected
function checkSelected(item) {
    return item != "undefined";
}

// Function to identify ID of record selected for deletion
function getSelected(selections) {
    var userID = selections.findIndex(checkSelected);
    return userID;
}

// REST endpoint for displaying data
app.get("/delete", function(req, res, next) {

    var radioArray = [];

    // Query database to retrieve records
    db.all(`SELECT * FROM UserLogin`, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        };

        // Generate table with user data
        res.write('<html><head>');
        res.write('<meta charset="utf-8">');
        res.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
        res.write('<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
        res.write("</head><body>");
        res.write("<h2> The User Information Table</h2><br>");
        res.write("<table class = 'table table-bordered table-striped'><thead><tr>");
        res.write("<strong><th>  </th>");
        res.write("<th>ID</th>");
        res.write("<th>Username</th>");
        res.write("<th>Password</th></strong></tr></thead><tbody>");

        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            res.write(`<tr><td><input type='radio' value='${row.ID}' id='optradio' name='optradio'></td><td>` +row.ID+ `</td><td>` +row.Username+ `</td><td>` +row.Password+ `</td></tr>`);
            radioArray.push(req.body.optradio);
        });

        res.write("</tbody></table></body></html><br>");
        res.write(`<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="delete" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>`);

        var whichRadio = getSelected(radioArray);

        db.run(`DELETE FROM UserLogin WHERE ID = ?`, whichRadio, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err.message);
            } console.log("Deleted ID " + whichRadio);

        });   

        res.send(); 
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Web server running at: http://localhost:3000");
console.log("Type Ctrl+C to shut down the web server");
});
```

Comment: May be this example will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/31730694/3254405

Comment: And you may need <form> tags if you getting radio buttons by name..

Comment: Thanks @numbtongue - I added a form and set up an app.post to get the radio button value, and all is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer to my question to help others with the same issue. Adding in form tags and setting up a separate POST method allowed me to get rid of the untidy code I was using to try and retrieve the radio button value, so the end result is neater.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var path = require('path');
var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

// Open persistent file database "loginDB"
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./loginDB', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the user database.');
  });


db.serialize(function() {
    db.run(`SELECT * FROM UserLogin`); 
});

// Route files in public
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Configure to use body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// REST endpoint for displaying data
app.get("/delete", function(req, res, next) {

    // Query database to retrieve records
    db.all(`SELECT * FROM UserLogin`, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        };

        // Generate table with user data
        res.write('<html><head>');
        res.write('<meta charset="utf-8">');
        res.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">');
        res.write('<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
        res.write("</head><body>");

        res.write("<h2> The User Information Table</h2><br>");
        res.write(`<form id="deleteUserForm" action="/inputForm" method="POST"</form>`);
        res.write("<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'><thead><tr><strong>");
        res.write("<th>  </th>");
        res.write("<th>ID</th>");
        res.write("<th>Username</th>");
        res.write("<th>Password</th></strong></tr></thead><tbody>");

        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            res.write(`<tr><td><input type='radio' form="deleteUserForm" value='${row.ID}' id='optradio' name='optradio'></td><td>` +row.ID+ `</td><td>` +row.Username+ `</td><td>` +row.Password+ `</td></tr>`);            
        });

        res.write("</tbody></table><br>");

        res.write(`<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" form="deleteUserForm" value="delete" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>`);
        res.write(`</body></html>`);

        res.send(); 
    });
});

// REST endpoint for getting value of selected record ID and deleting the user
app.post('/inputForm', function(req, res) {
    //res.send(req.body.optradio);
    var userToDelete = req.body.optradio;

    db.run(`DELETE FROM UserLogin WHERE ID = ?`, userToDelete, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
        } res.redirect('/delete');      //Redirect to user information page      
    }); 
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Web server running at: http://localhost:3000");
console.log("Type Ctrl+C to shut down the web server");
});
```